Confusion about finding poles by inspection
I have a few doubts regarding finding poles by inspection and why sometimes the 'quick, intuitive' techniques do not work.
Question 1
Consider the circuit shown in figure 1 below:

By manually writing the impedance equation and equating the numerator to 0 to find zeros and denominator to zero to find poles, we find that there is one pole at 0 (origin) and one zero at s = - 1/(R1·C1).
This can also be found by inspection. To find zeros by inspection, we think of what the impedance of this series combination has to be in order for the output to be zero. To find the pole by inpsection, we think of what the impedance has to be for the output to be infinite.
A third way is described here by Verbal Kint which associated poles with nodes and the respective R to AC GND and C to AC GND as seen on that node. How can I apply that method here? Does that technique not work for series impedances like this?
Question 2
Consider the next circuit shown in figure 2 below:

In this case, by manually writing the impedance equation and equating the numerator to 0 to find zeros and denominator to zero to find poles, we find that there is a pole at zero (integrator), a zero at -1/(R1·C1) and then an additional pole at -1/(R1·Ceq) where Ceq = (C1·C2)/(C1+C2)
This confuses me. A pole causes the output to go to infinity. So, at a complex frequency s = 0, both C1 impedance will be infinite and C2 impedance will be infinite. Hence, there should be two poles at s = 0. Why is this not the case?


Consider the circuit shown in figure 1 below:

The circuit is not complete. For example if the source is a voltage source with zero resistance, the R and C components have no effect.

By manually writing the impedance equation and equating the numerator to 0 to find zeros and denominator to zero to find poles, we find that there is one pole at 0 (origin) and one zero at s = - 1/(R1*C1).

To find the poles and zeros by inspection, the type of source must be known.
So for a voltage source with a Thevenin resistance \$R_{Th}\$, there is one pole at \$s=-\frac{1}{(R_{Th}+R_1)C_1}\$ and one zero at \$s=-\frac{1}{R_1C_1}\$.

How can I apply [Verbal Kint's] method here??


To determine the time constants of a circuit, you must reduce the excitation or the stimulus to zero: you turn the source off. Here, the stimulus is Vin
and when made 0 V, it can be replaced by a wire in the circuit. (Verbal Kint)

Yes it can. Setting the voltage source to zero will result in shorting out the circuit, showing that {for an ideal voltage source) the circuit has no poles and Vout is always the same as Vin.
For an ideal current source, setting the source to zero implies an open circuit. So then by inspection, there is a zero at \$s=\frac{-1}{R_1C_1}\$ and a pole at the origin.
For Question 2.
The answer for Question 1 still holds. The input source must be specified. For an ideal voltage source Vout will equal Vin.
For an ideal current source, all the poles and zero's identified are correct.

So, at a complex frequency s = 0, both C1 impedance will be infinite and C2 impedance will be infinite. Hence, there should be two poles at s = 0. Why is this not the case?

At very low frequency, R1 is insignificant, so the two capacitors act as one. So only one pole at the origin.

This is my choice for the answers so far. The indicated questions by the OP show very little understanding. So you had a bit of a slog and despite that did a great job, I think. So I'm +1.

Appreciated @periblepsis

Excellent Answer. One question, you mention " For an ideal current source, setting the source to zero implies an open circuit. So then by inspection ". Verbal Kint's method was looking for resistancce seen to AC ground when the voltage source is shorted out, what are you looking for when there instead a current source that is open circuited like you mentioned?

All the time constants of course. @Verbal Kint knows his work better than I. Perhaps you could ask him.

All of these answers are good and I am glad to see people interested by the FACTs. I am always surprised not to see them more widely taught. Anyway, I have added my own answer below with a few intermediate sketches for the first question:

In the first case, the circuit is driven by a voltage source affected by a resistance, otherwise, as correctly underlined by RussellH, there won't be no effect in the transfer function (TF). It is a first-order TF and the pole is obtained while the voltage source is zeroed (shorted). The zero is found by determining the impedance condition which would shunt the response to ground and it is obviously the series combination of \$R_1\$ and \$C_1\$. For the impedance, you see that the resistance offered at dc in infinite (\$R_{inf}\$) so you just carry on with the analysis and factor \$R_{inf}\$ in the end. The pole at the origin can be advantageously factored to resort to an inverted zero, offering the most compact notation. FACTs are not just about find transfer functions quickly, but also writing them in a low-entropy format.
For the second question, again, the result depends whether this a voltage or current source that drives the circuit. In the first case, a series of small sketches quickly leads to the answer:

A quick Mathcad sheet shows the similar plots of the different TF, the final one being written with the low-\$Q\$ approximation:

Now, for the impedance, same procedure as before:

If you do the maths ok, after rearranging the impedance in the correct low-entropy format, you will find a pole at the origin, when the zero kicks in, the impedance flattens out to the mid-band resistance and, finally, the second pole rolls the impedance off as frequency increases:

These FACTs are simple to apply as long as you carefully draw the small intermediate steps. This is what took me so long in my last book on the subject  : )

Excellent Answer. This FACTs technique is really useful. I must buy your book to read more about it.

For question 1, it's easier to find the input admittance (i.e. we put a test voltage source at the top node), and then take the inverse for finding the input impedance. I'm going to use the method explained by C. Basso (aka Verbal Kint here), which originates from Hajimiri's article, which in turn is based on the Cochrun-Grabel method published in the 70s.
To that end, we solve the following equation (We all know it's a 1st-order system):
$$
Y_{in}(s)=\frac{a_0+a_1s}{1+b_1s}
$$
\$a_0\$, in this case, is the input admittance when all the dynamic elements are in their DC state. \$C_1\$ is an open, therefore, \$a_0 = 0 \Omega^{-1}\$.
\$b_1\$ is the linear sum of the all the time constants associated with each dynamic element while all others are set to their DC state. In this case, we only have one dynamic element, \$C_1\$. It's trivial to see the resistance seen by \$C_1\$ is \$R_1\$, therefore \$\tau_{C_1}=C_1R_1=b_1\$.
For the \$a_1\$ term, we sum all transfer functions (in this case, the input admittance) with each dynamic element set to its infinite-frequency state (i.e. a capacitor = short), and each is multiplied by the \$\tau\$ associated with the dynamic element whose infinite-frequency state is being set. In this case, we find the that input admittance while \$C_1\rightarrow\infty\$ is simply \$Y_1=\frac{1}{R_1}\$. We multiply this times \$\tau_{C_1}\$.
Therefore, we arrive at the following expression:
$$
Y_{in}(s)=\frac{sY_1C_1R_1}{1+C_1R_1s}=\frac{sC_1}{1+C_1R_1s}
$$
When we take the inverse, we can easily that the zero is at \$-\frac{1}{R_1C_1}\$, while there's a pole at the origin, which makes sense as the impedance of this network is infinite at DC at decreases as frequency increases.
For question 2, as the other answerers said, at DC both capacitors have infinite impedance, thus they act as a single capacitor. It's still 2nd order, as you said, but not due to a double integrator at the origin.

I can't answer your first question but, for your 2nd question (when s falls towards zero), the effective impedance of the series resistor and capacitor falls towards being wholly defined by the capacitor hence, what remains are two capacitors in parallel. Of course they can be equated to one capacitor hence, there is only one pole when s=0.
